# Flexbox inside nested column layout in Angular Material not working in WebKit

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, flexbox, angular-material

We are trying to use a flexed column nested inside some other flexboxes using Angular Material. It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome (v. 48 or 50) or Safari (v. 9).

Here is a some code that reproduces the issue:

```
<body layout="column">
    <div layout="row">navbar</div>
    <div flex layout="row">
      <div>sidebar</div>
      <div flex layout="row">
        <div id="content" layout="column">
          <div flex style="background-color: blue;">
            content1
          </div>
          <div flex="20" style="background-color: yellow;">
            content2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

We would expect that "content1" and "container2" respectively would fill 80% and 20% of the container, but in WebKit both fill 50% of the container instead.

If we change the layout of the element with id `content` to `"row"` instead of `"column"`, it works in WebKit, but we need the content to be in a column.

Here is a codepen showing the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGaRYX?editors=1000

Answer (score -1):

In order to use the column flex, your container needs to have a specified height. If you add `layout-fill` on each outer container, all of them will have a `height: 100%` and the `flex="20"` will work. You will however have a scrollbar since the 100% height don't take into account your navbar.
You can use `calc(100vh - NAVBAR_HEIGHT)` on the outer container instead of `layout-fill` to fix this.

```
<body layout="column">
<div layout="row" style="height: 50px">navbar</div>
<div layout="row" style="height: calc(100vh - 50px)">
  <div>sidebar</div>
  <div flex layout-fill layout="row">
    <div id="content" flex layout-fill layout="column">
      <div flex style="background-color: blue;">
        content1
      </div>
      <div flex="20" style="background-color: yellow;">
        content2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/ZQPBxg

Comment: So there is no way to achieve what I want, if the height of the navbar can vary? (I might want it to make it a flexbox too)

Comment: You can actually do it without `calc`. You can flex the navbar but still need to set the height on the main container. http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/KVENjj